# Convert RenderTargetBitmap to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage, rendertargetbitmap

I have a `RenderTargetBitmap`, I need to convert it to `BitmapImage`. Please check the code below.

```
 RenderTargetBitmap bitMap = getRenderTargetBitmap();
 Image image = new Image();// This is a Image
 image.Source = bitMap;
```

In the above code I have used Image.Now I need to use a BitmapImage. How can I do this?

```
 RenderTargetBitmap bitMap = getRenderTargetBitmap();
 BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();// This is a BitmapImage
 // how to set bitMap as source of BitmapImage ?
```

Comment: Georges,I need to convert the RenderTargetBitmap to BitmapImage.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [RenderTargetBitmap to BitmapImage in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361579/rendertargetbitmap-to-bitmapimage-in-wpf)

Comment: something like that : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969819.aspx

Comment: Please explain why exactly you need to have a BitmapImage? RenderTargetBitmap and BitmapImage have a common base class [BitmapSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx), which provides all the basic bitmap properties.

Comment: MSDN: "BitmapImage primarily exists to support Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) syntax and introduces additional properties for bitmap loading that are not defined by BitmapSource.". Do you really need that?

Comment: The questioner doesn't mention it, but you cannot set RenderTargetBitmap.Rotation but you can set BitmapImage.Rotation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Although it doesn't seem to be necessary to convert a `RenderTargetBitmap` into a `BitmapImage`, you could easily encode the `RenderTargetBitmap` into a `MemoryStream` and decode the `BitmapImage` from that stream.

There are several [BitmapEncoders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx) in WPF, the sample code below uses a `PngBitmapEncoder`.

```
var renderTargetBitmap = getRenderTargetBitmap();
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
var bitmapEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
bitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmapEncoder.Save(stream);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap bitMap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await bitMap.RenderAsync(grid);
    Image image = new Image();// This is a Image
    image.Source = bitMap;
    image.Height = 150;
    image.Width = 100;

    grid.Children.Add(image);
}
```

This looks as a simpler solution.

Comment: Please answer in English and ask questions as separate questions (or via comments when you have enough reputation)

Comment: This isn't even a solution at all (despite a simpler one), because it does not create a BitmapImage, as was asked for in the question.