# How do I convert a WriteableBitmap object to a BitmapImage Object in WPF

Tags: wpf, bitmapimage, writeablebitmap

How do I convert a `WriteableBitmap` object to a `BitmapImage` Object in WPF?

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986638/how-can-i-convert-writeablebitmap-to-bitmapimage) covers silverlight, the process is not the same in WPF as the `WriteableBitmap` object does not have a `SaveJpeg` method.

So my question is How do I convert a `WriteableBitmap` object to a `BitmapImage` Object in WPF?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13988871/1136211) and replace RenderTargetBitmap by WriteableBitmap. Why exactly do you need this conversion? It's usually not necessary, since BitmapImage and WriteableBitmap have a common base class BitmapSource which provides all relevant properties of an image.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use one of the `BitmapEncoders` to save the `WriteableBitmap` frame to a new `BitmapImage`

In this example we will use the `PngBitmapEncoder` but just choose the one that fits your situation.

```
public BitmapImage ConvertWriteableBitmapToBitmapImage(WriteableBitmap wbm)
{
    BitmapImage bmImage = new BitmapImage();
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wbm));
        encoder.Save(stream);
        bmImage.BeginInit();
        bmImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bmImage.StreamSource = stream;
        bmImage.EndInit();
        bmImage.Freeze();
    }
    return bmImage;
}
```

usage:

```
 BitmapImage bitmap = ConvertWriteableBitmapToBitmapImage(your writable bitmap);
```

or you could make this an extension method for easy use

```
public static class ImageHelpers
{
    public static BitmapImage ToBitmapImage(this WriteableBitmap wbm)
    {
        BitmapImage bmImage = new BitmapImage();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wbm));
            encoder.Save(stream);
            bmImage.BeginInit();
            bmImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bmImage.StreamSource = stream;
            bmImage.EndInit();
            bmImage.Freeze();
        }
        return bmImage;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
WriteableBitmap wbm = // your writeable bitmap

BitmapImage bitmap = wbm.ToBitmapImage();
```

Comment: And don't forget to rewind the stream. After saving, before setting `bmImage.StreamSource` do a `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`. Some decoders (e.g. JPG) require this. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13988871/1136211).

Comment: Thankyou both, most helpful!

Comment: @JMK Still i doubt that it's really necessary to do this conversion.