# MVVM Writeablebitmap Image processing

Tags: mvvm, writeablebitmap

The idea is to process a loaded image. I first wanted to process it that way, that there is a white/black line going through the image.
Actual the problem is, that a new Thread (for Thread.Sleep) freezes the whole UI, while processing. And when I try a Dispatcher, the image doesn't update.

So I got a ProcessingClass:

```
public WriteableBitmap GetProcessedPicture(int i)
        {
            WriteableBitmap wb = image.image;

            Process(ref wb, i);

            return wb;
        }

        private void Process(ref WriteableBitmap wb, int j)
        {
            int stride = wb.PixelWidth * (wb.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;

            byte[] data = new byte[stride * wb.PixelHeight];

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) data[i] = 255;

//just to see some changes
            wb.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(j, 0, 100, 100), data, stride, 0);

        }
```

And the MainViewModel class (I'm using MVVM light) with:

```
public void Start_Click()
        {
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                ImageSource = processingClass.GetProcessedPicture(i);

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }));

            };
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `ImageSource` (assuming it binds to Image.Source) accepts a `WriteableBitmap`. You have to convert it to a `BitmapImage` first!

Adjusting your code a bit I'd do something like:

```
public void Start_Click()
{
    var t = new Task(() =>
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var writeablebitmap = processingClass.GetProcessedPicture(i);
            var bitmapImage = processingClass.ConvertToBitmapImage(writeablebitmap);

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                ImageSource = bitmapImage;
            }));

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    });
    t.Start();
}
```

This way you're not stalling the UI thread with your image processing, but you  still update the image on the UI thread.

As for converting your `WriteableBitmap` to a `BitmapImage`, there are plenty of resources available on the internet, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161665/how-do-i-convert-a-writeablebitmap-object-to-a-bitmapimage-object-in-wpf)

Comment: Yes, `ImageSource` is Image.Source, but it accepts `WriteableBitmap` there is no problem when I initialize it.
But I tried your code and it throws me the same `InvalidOperationException`, I got eralier.

Comment: Did you create the WriteableBitmap on the UI thread? Otherwise that might expain your `InvalidOperationException`. You might also want to read the Remarks at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx to make sure you're doing it right when it comes to threading.